# NativeScript Angular singleton service

Tags: angular, nativescript

I want to create a service that keeps running when the user navigates out of the application using the back button. I have achieved this by using setInterval in an Angular service like this:

```
export class StartupService {
public id: string;

constructor() {
    //create a random id for logging
    this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log(this.id + " StartupService " + new Date());
    },1000);
}
}
```

When the user resumes the application another instance of this service is created however. Both of the setIntervals are running however (2 messages per second printed out on the screen with different ids, expected single id printed 1x per second). So the initial service is still somewhere in memory and could be reused instead of creating a new one.

Is it possible to achieve this scenario with NativeScript and Angular?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: you must to add as a `provider` in the root parent module  then you will keep the same instance

Comment: it is already in the providers list in app.module.ts (which is also the root module imo)

Comment: you can keep track of the background event just like u r doing the result and keep the last state in storage as soon as app is goes to background and then on resume, get that stored value and use it.